# Laptop not booting after Windows 10 Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, windows-10-upgrade

I have a **Lenovo Y560 Laptop** which had Windows 7 installed on it. Everything seemed fine until I started getting the Notifications on my Desktop for getting the Windows 10 update. I was already very apprehensive about getting the update fearing it would hamper the machine. However, I decided to go ahead with the update. The update and installation took very long but it was successful.

The problem started when I started my Laptop after the first shut down. Before it came to the Windows home screen, a blue screen would pop up saying ***"Your PC ran into a problem"***. It would never boot till the home screen for me to try any fix mentioned in various forums. All the troubleshooting options during the startup also did not work including *Reinstall, System Restore and Getting back to Windows7 build.*

I was finally left with the last resort of Downloading the **Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB ISO** on my USB stick and installing it from scratch. Now this has left me with a Blank C drive and just 90 days of Validity. I am in extreme despair. Somebody please help me as to how to either get a valid Windows 10 or get back to the old version.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to use system recovery built-in to the laptop to restore it to Windows 7, or obtain a recovery/reinstall Windows 7 disc from Lenovo and restore the system to original, out of box state. The Windows 7 OEM recovery disk plus your bios will automatically register Win 7, then you can attempt to upgrade to 10 again if you want... Or if your Win 10 install seems fine, purchase the license for it from Microsoft.

Comment: Hard Reset (Recovery using Button on Laptop) will wipe out everything, won't it?! And, do I need to pay for the Windows 10 License even though I had a licensed Windows 7?

Comment: Yes... Your "free" Windows 10 upgrade is only if upgraded from a properly activated previous Windows version. If you have to reinstall for some reason, you have to go back to original OS, activate it, then upgrade it. Personally I think the "free" upgrade is just a gimmick to get you buy it later out of convenience

Comment: I contacted Microsoft Support directly over phone and after some time of waiting, I got an answer from the Support Engineer that My Laptop is not compatible for Windows 10. He said the only option is to roll back to Windows 7 and lose all the data. 
I mean, seriously!? Why did I even get a notification in the first place for updating to Windows 10? This is atrocious.

Comment: The sounds like a cop-out answer... I haven't seen a modern laptop that is "incompatible" with Win 10... Some features may not work properly though.